# Onclick event not working with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I am new to html

I am trying to add a onclick event with radio button but it is not working. I am unable to figure out the reason. Please help.

```
Example code
<script>
    function select(btn)
    {
     var1=document.getElementById("radio1");
     var2=document.getElementById("radio2");
     var3=document.getElementById("radio3");
     if(var1.checked==true)
     {
        document.myform.action="A.html";
     }
     elseif(var2.checked==true)
     {
        document.myform.action="B.html";
     }
     else
     {
        document.myform.action="C.html";
     }
   }
</script>

function test()
{
alert('Testing')
}

{% block radio_buttons %}
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="project_type" value=0 checked    onclick="alert('yes')"><label>Projects I own</label> -->
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="project_type" value=0 checked onclick="select('this')"><label>Projects I own</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="test()"><label>Projects I manage</label>
<br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="select()"><label>Projects I can edit</label>
<br>
{% endblock %}
```

This code I have added in templates. I tried adding alerts. Alert get exceuted but not onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` function contains a syntax error and is therefore never executed.
Write:

```
 else if (var2.checked==true)
```

instead of

```
 elseif (var2.checked==true)
```

To avoid these kind of errors open the developer console of your browser and check if syntax errors are shown.

Second the choice of `select` for the function name is unfortunate, since input elements have a `select` function which is called instead of your function.
To avoid this rename your function (e.g. `radioSelect`) and call it accordingly (`onclick="radioSelect(this);"`).

Also your `test` function is placed outside of a script element which is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for help. I am able to run the html page standalone. But I am running this page with django and my template is using template inheritance as well. Now when I merge this again my page is not exceuted.   
     
 
     
Also please help me understand I want to populate a drop-down based on user selection of radio button from the django form. How can i do that? I need to extract the value from my database. If there is any example or link that will surely help. Thanks

Comment: @user3364086 you got two answers for your original question. If they helped you should upvote or accept them to show that you appreciated this effort. If you have follow-up questions then simply post another question.

Comment: @wero did you run my snippet? it works. it calls the alert which was the desired outcome. OP can not upvote, you need 15 rep to upvote

Comment: @RachelGallen: yes I ran it. The `select` function is not called (I use the latest firefox).

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few syntax errors in your code. And you don't need the (btn) after your select in your function. You have omitted a few semi-colons, not least the one after the testing alert.

This code works

```html
<head>
    <script>
    function select() {
    var1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var3 = document.getElementById("radio3");
    if (var1.selected === true) {
        document.myform.action = "A.html";
    }
    else if(var2.selected === true) {
        document.myform.action = "B.html";
    } else {
        document.myform.action = "C.html";
    }
}


function test() {
    alert('Testing');
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="project_type" value=0 checked onclick="alert('yes')"><label>Projects I own</label> -->
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="project_type" value=0 checked onclick="select();">
    <label>Projects I own</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="test();">
    <label>Projects I manage</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="select();">
    <label>Projects I can edit</label>
</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/cqdd072n/)

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for help. I am able to run the html page standalone. But I am running this page with django and my template is using template inheritance as well. Now when I merge this again my page is not exceuted.

Comment: Also please help me understand I want to populate a drop-down based on user selection of radio button from the django form. How can i do that? I need to extract the value from my database. If there is any example or link that will surely help. Thanks

Comment: thats a seperate question. i know v little about django

Comment: @RachelGallen your answer does not work. See my remark about the use of the `select` function.

Comment: Thanks I have accepted your answer and marked it green.  I will post a separate question for django

Comment: @user3364086 for future reference you can only accept one answer. you cannot mark multiple as green.

Comment: @user3364086 i note that you now have enough rep to upvote. Please upvote my answer. Its worth 10 points to me, and if you get a badge for your first upvote (and another if you use 30 votes in a day!) thanks,,, I think i deserve it seeing as this was initially marked as accepted!